# How to get entity size in GAE/J?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

GAE documentation mentions that the max entity size is 1Mb. Since I'm storing a lot of data inside entities I'd like to know when I'm approaching this limit.

I'm aware of GAE/Pyhon method [`model_to_protobuf(..)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#model_to_protobuf), but I can't find anything for Java.

I'm also aware that GAE uses protobuf internally to serialize entities, so I could do the same. But I'd like to avoid duplicate code as GAE is already doing this under the hood.

Is there a programmatic way to get entity size in Java, preferably before entity is actually stored?

Comment: this question is interesting. I wonder if toString.getBytes() would not be enough? This could be helpful for me too.

Comment: btw, I would like to ask you for your experience with GAE about Datastore queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979142/ordering-query-results-by-date-string-for-gae -- I hope you can check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [this method](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/EntityTranslator#convertToPb%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity%29) should fit the bill for you:

```
public static EntityProto convertToPb(Entity entity)
```

and matches up with what you've found on the Python side.