# Ordering Query results by Date (String) for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have thousands of Entities stored in the GAE datastore where a field "create" is saved as a date `String` (standard format).

**My question would be**, is it still possible to do a `Query` like this:

```
Query q = new Query("Post")
                .addSort("created", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
```

Where "`created`" is actually a date String, stored like this: `2014-12-11T14:31:43 -08:00"`
and actually get a descending order. I've tried it but the result set is just as random and not even in order by date.

Is there a way to tweak a GAE `Query` to achieve this with this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if GAE has indexed date as string so '2014-12-**11**T14:31:43 -08:00' comes after '2014-12-**04**T14:31:43 -08:00' (just for example) which means natural sorting order should follow.

Have you indexed 'created' field? If not, GAE is gonna ignore the sort order you gave in query.

Comment: yes, as it is saved into the Entity with 'setProperty' method (thus indexed)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work that way.

You need the property to be a Date type.

```
import java.util.Date;

Date created = new Date();
Post.setProperty("created", created);
```

Maybe you can do a task to update all your entities with the created string actually being cast as a date and save it.

Comment: There must be some way to do this without having to update all as new entities will be saved with that String date anyway

Comment: *must* there be? More likely you'll need to run a batch job to convert them to real datetime entities. Thousands is not many for this sort of task.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood what if the problem is not with just the data, but with lots of apps storing in the same Datastore and some apps store date as String (at least well formatted). Thus even if you run a batch convert for a specific set of data, more data will come in with date stored as well-formatted String.

Comment: You have to convert the type to Datetime... And btw, whats the point on storing a datetime as string?

Comment: sounds like you have more then one problem to deal with then.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood the answer from apt_coder makes sense, what do you think of it? Indeed date String must have natural ordering, do you see any catch from that answer?

Comment: if it works, it works. But if you have many apps writing data and only "some" store a "well formatted" string your searches simply won't reliably work across the entire dataset and you probably won't even know it without extensive testing.